# How to automatically scrolling to the bottom of a text file window?

Tags: javascript, php, scroll

I have a button that opens a TXT file in a new window.  Is there a way to automatically go to the very bottom of that page using javascript or php?  Or to any particular location (like searching for a string)?  Because it is a TXT file, there are no anchors.

Here's my button's onclick:

```
onclick="window.open('comments.txt','_comments').focus();"
```

I have looked into adding this to the onclick (but it did not work):

```
w.scrollTo(0,150);
```

Comment: It is impossible to execute the javascript in new-opened window. You can only use an iframe.

Comment: @Mathematician171 I thought so, but I gave it a try and it actually works! Wonderful.

Comment: @blex Yes, it works on same domain. But, if domains of fisrt and second page are different, it doesn't work. For example, it is not possible to write a javascript code on one site to open a Facebook page and execute a script.

Comment: @Mathematician171 That's correct. It would be a nightmare otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>This is a test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="open">Open text file</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('open').onclick = function(){
            window.open('comments.txt','_comments').onload = function(){
                this.scrollTo(0, 99999); // Use the biggest value you can
            };
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Make sure you do this from a server (not locally), as browsers check that the files are on the same domain (for security reasons). If you want to work directly on your machine, install a [local server](http://www.wampserver.com/) and use `http://localhost/`.*

**Note:** Here, I scroll to 99999px, because without an actual HTML document, we're not able to find out the document height. If that's not enough, use a higher value.